# Trying to space out each of my output lines (creating a flipped triangle)

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to add a space to the beginning of my output for every line. For every line, it will add more space between as it goes through each line to get the flipped triangle.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// compiler issue on 2nd digit 

int main(){

long long number;

printf("Enter a number\n");
printf("Enter your number = ");
scanf("%lld", &number);


    for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){
    for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j-1); i++){
       printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
    
   }
       printf("\n");

   }

   
   return 0;
}
```

---

My output:

```
Enter a number
Enter your number = 12345
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2
5   4   3
5   4
5
```

What I'm trying to output:

```
Enter a number
Enter your number = 12345
 5   4   3   2   1
   5   4   3   2
     5   4   3
       5   4
         5
```

---

A sample program as what I had in mind

```
int main()
{
    int l;
    for(l=0; l<3; l++){
        printf("%*s Moving\n", l, "");
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the latter idea to work and insert a `printf("%*s", 2*j-1, "");` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! I'm trying to create an hourglass, I'm guessing I need to copy and paste my nested for-loops again, but flip to the bottom triangle?

Comment: Right, running the `j` loop in reverse would print a triangle pointing up.